# google tag manager run after aquia lift

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I am getting a customer segment from aquia lift and I need to run this ...:

`jQuery(document).bind('acquiaLiftWebSegments', function (event, segments, currentCapture) {`

... before the tag manager runs. But the tag manager is running first.

How can I make the tag manager run after that event?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to fire some tags after this event because running empty container has no sense. So you can push some event to dataLayer and use this event as a firing rule in your tag's trigger.